# Combining $resource & non-$resource methods in Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Not sure why this, seemingly simple, task is confusing me. I'm trying to add some methods to an Angular service. The service started out just making one `$resource` call to my API. What I'm adding are simple non-$resource methods that save and get a local object:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gameApp')
  .factory('searchService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/search?query=:query';
      var latestResults = {};

      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getResults: {method: 'GET', url: base}
      }),
      saveLatest: function(results) {
        latestResults = results;
      },
      getLatest: function() {
        return latestResults;
      }
    }]);
```

Apparently the above is not structured correctly at all (as far as `saveLatest` and `getLatest` are concerned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up right now you are returning multiple comma-delineated values at the same time, which is not possible (assuming this is not ES6). You either need to return an array or object that has the three return values in it:

```
return [
  $resource(base, {}, {
    getResults: {method: 'GET', url: base}
  }),
  function(results) {
    latestResults = results;
  },
  function() {
    return latestResults;
  }]
```

or

```
return {
    resource: $resource(base, {}, {
        getResults: {method: 'GET', url: base}
    }),
    saveLatest: function(results) {
        latestResults = results;
      },
    getLatest: function() {
        return latestResults;
    }
}
```

Additionally, there is generally not a reason to expose the entire $resource object, so it might be better to return just the getResults method of it.

Answer (score 1):

The object you return should be in the form

```
return {
   method1: function(){...},
   method2: function(){...},
   method3: function(){...},
};
```

Yours looks like this:

```
return method1(),
       method2: function(){...},
       method3: function(){...}
```

Hopefully, you can see the material difference in the above.

Your code should probably look something like the below based on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

```
return {
    getResults: $resource(base,{method: 'GET', url: base}),
    saveLatest: function(results) {
        latestResults = results;
    },
    getLatest: function() {
        return latestResults;
    }
}
```